# How to technically guarantee BYOK data privacy in Azure

Tags: azure, key, azure-keyvault, hsm, key-management

Can data stored in Azure using BYOK (storage accounts, databases etc) be technically (rather than contractually) assured to be not to be access even from Microsoft? For example we assume the HSM key has been securely transferred to HSM backed Key Vault. How can application write to and read from storage using BYOK without Microsoft being able to peek in configuration, or in memory process, or while data is saved to storage?

Answer (score 0):

In [public preview now](https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/akv-managed-hsm-public-preview) you can use Managed HSM (MHSM). You can provision an MHSM similar to a Key Vault (KV), but to activate and use it you need to set up 3 or more keys to download a security domain from the HSM. Microsoft has no access to decrypt the key - only a quorum of the 3 or more public keys you uploaded. While a bit specific to our testing environment, we have a [script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/test-resources-post.ps1) that shows how we create certificates and download the security domain using those public keys in order to test MHSM.

You can use the existing Key Vault SDKs and tools like the [Azure CLI](https://aka.ms/azure/cli) to access MHSM just like you would KV. For the Azure CLI you need to pass `--hsm-name` instead of `--vault-name`, but otherwise works the same for keys.

We are soon releasing another beta of the Azure SDKs for .NET, Java, JavaScript, and Python that support other algorithms supported by MHSM (AES-CBC, AES-CBC-PAD, and AES-GCM). Check out our [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/) for announcements.

Comment: Thank you @Heath if I understand your answer correctly it applies to transfer and management of BYOK keys. But BYOK on its own cannot guarantee protection of data-in-use, and customers looking for technical (rather than contractual) data protection guarantees should look at Azure confidential computing?

Comment: A private key is generated in an HSM and can never leave the HSM by design. You remain in total control of the private keys corresponding to the public keys used to create the security domain. Microsoft never has access to any of this - all secured via implementation and design of an HSM, not contract. You can then use these same keys to encrypt data at rest in Storage, SQL, and other services that support it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-atrest for details.